# Implementing gravity in simple 2d game

Tags: java, physics

I'm making a simple game, something like mario, with a character fixed in one position, and the ground moving left, giving the illusion of character movement. The ground is made of rectangular blocks defined by top-left and bottom-right coordinates:

```
private int surfaceMatrix[][] = {
   {0, 100, 300, 0} // block having 100 height and 300 width
};
```

Jumping is just changing character's y coordinate while moving the surface left, so the jump looks like reversed `V` letter.

The rest of the code - animation, moving sprites - is very similar to http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/movingsprites/

---

I want jumping to be more real, so my question is - how can I implement gravity here? I'd have to use dx of the ground, and dy of the character to do it, is that ok?

What would be the velocity here? Pixels per second...?

How to do that?

Comment: How do you calculate the height of the character now when he jumps? Is it pixel based? If so how do you support different resolutions? I would assume you calculate a relative position to the ground and then a final calculation based on actual resolution. If that is the case, gravity is merely a slightly more complex falling function than height-1 over time.

Comment: Well, right now the resolution is fixed, and so is character's height.

Comment: It is trivial to allow for resolution changes if you don't calculate the pixels per se but use relative heights. But if you are using a fixed resolution, you know how high he jumps (say 50 pixels), I assume you draw him multiple times while he is falling down, currently using a fixed interval (say 5px depending on your refresh rate) so use the default a slightly more complex method to calculate the actual drop instead of fixed 5px, say "5px+(iteration*5px). This is too simplistic of course but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see:

```
g = 9.8 meters/second
```

Take height of your character in pixels and match it to an average man height, say 1.7 meters tall.

Then use gravitation formula:

```
y = y0 - g * t^2 / 2
```

where **g** is in pixels/second.

Comment: I can see two problems here. What would be time here? Miliseconds from the timer multiplied by 10^3? And y has to be float here, so should I just round it?

Comment: @user3486978 It's presudo-code, not Java. But yes, you should round it. As for time - measure it however you want (e.g. with System.currentTimeMillis()) and convert to seconds then.